# How to access Oracle 10g Server over a Local Area Network?

Tags: database, oracle, connectivity, ora-12170

I installed Oracle 10g server Express edition on a System(say host-a[100.101.102.103])

And I tried access the database from another system(say host-b[100.101.102.104]) using the
command on the sql command line

```
"**connect username/password@100.101.102.103:1521/XE**"
```

But it says something like

> request timeout.**ORA-12170:TNS:Connect timeout occured**

... where I made mistake....

1. All the username, password and ip all are correct.
2. Both Systems are in the same Local Area Connection....

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a firewall that prevents connecting to your database by silently dropping the network packets.

Is the database on a Windows server with the Windows Firewall activated? If yes, you need to create an exception for port 1521 (and potentially for 2030 and 8080 as well).